# Determining Naval Interceptions

Tags: empires-in-arms

I have a complicated situation involving four major powers.  The below chart will summarize their relations.  Both sets of allies are using simultaneous movement.

```
         France   Russia    Spain   Turkey
France       XX   Allied      War      ---
Russia   Allied       XX      War      War
Spain       War      War       XX   Allied
Turkey      ---      War   Allied       XX
```

French and Russian fleets are blockading the Spanish and Turkish fleets at Cadiz.

Spain & Turkey wish to run the blockade together as one stack.  **Who can intercept and why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check 6.3.1.2.

There is relevant errata published in The General #27.2.

Short: if France and Russia declare a combined movement, they can intercept and fight together against Turkey and Spain. 
If there is no combined movement then in turn France and Russia can try to intercept and if they succeed can battle both Turkey and Spain, with an opportunity for France to DoW Turkey.